# Changing Password using if and else block

Tags: c#, asp.net, if-statement

I am the admin who wants to change the password for anyone by entering their email address and the new password in textbox.The stored procedure is as below:

```
   Alter proc spChangePassword
  @Email varchar(100),
 @Passwordd varchar(100)
  as
   begin
   IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tblRegister WHERE Email=@Email) 
   begin
   UPDATE tblRegister
   SET Passwordd=@Passwordd where Email=@Email
  Select 0
   end
  ELSE
   BEGIN
  Select -1
  end
   end
```

and the code-behind is as below:

```
private void ChangePassword()
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABCD"].ConnectionString;
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spChangePassword", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email",txtEmail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passwordd", txtPassword.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ChangePassword();
}
```

But i want to check if the email exists in the table using if and else statements.If the email exists then change password else throw an exception.What can i do?

Comment: cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passwordd", txtPassword.Text);Change the  line like this.

Comment: *But i want to check if the email exists in the table using if and else statments* Just return `@@ROWCOUNT`. `0` => user didn't exist.

Comment: @Ullas - Thats just a typo.

Comment: @ta.speot.is - and that would be in my stored procedure right?

Comment: Yes. If you return @@ROWCOUNT as @ta.speot.is says, you can check the return value on your C# code and if its 0, then no row was updated, meaning the email does not exist

Comment: You are not storing passwords in plain text, are you?

Comment: @DanielBrückner - Yes i am.Thats intentional tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could simply change a bit the code of your procedure and have it to return a value. 
0 would mean that the password updated and -1 that there is not an email like the one provided.

```
ALTER proc spChangePassword
    @Email varchar(100),
    @Passwordd varchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM Users WHERE Email=@Email) THEN 
BEGIN
    UPDATE tblRegister
    SET Passwordd=@Passwordd where Email=@Email
    SELECT 0 AS Result
END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        SELECT -1 AS Result
    END
END
```

Then you have to read the result of the stored procedure and act correspondingly. So your server side code must be changed to the following:

```
var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read()) 
{
    if(int.Parse(reader["Result"].ToString())==0)
    {
         // success
    }
    else
    {
        // failure
    }
};
```

**update** In the `if` statement, you could also use this one:

```
Convert.ToInt32(reader["Result"])==0
```

I think it will work like a charm.

Comment: @Mash sure but what you mean you mean use it in the code? What is that you are not get, in order to help you. Thanks !

Comment: I guess its ExecuteNonQuery() and i am still gettin an error saying int doesnt contain defintion for Read

Comment: @Mash I got it. Give me few minutes to fix it. Thanks for being patient.

Comment: int.Parse(string) has invalid arguements

Answer (score 0):

### Inside your Stored procedure add this

```
    Begin
    DECLARE @id AS INT
    SELECT @id = tblRegisterId FROM tblRegisterWHERE Email =@Email 
    IF @id IS not NULL
     Begin 
       UPDATE tblRegister
       SET Passwordd=@Passwordd where Email=@Email
       Select 1
     End
    Else
        Begin 
      Select 0
     End
    End
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :-

```
private bool ChangePassword()
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABCD"].ConnectionString;
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spChangePassword", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email",txtEmail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passwordd", txtPassword.Text);
        int count = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        if (count > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bool success = ChangePassword(); //Use this success variable to show a message.
}
```

You can also change your stored procedure, but it wont throw any exception, only it will check.  If the Email exists, it will execute the update query :-

```
Create proc spChangePassword
  @Email varchar(100),
  @Passwordd varchar(100)
as
begin
IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tblRegister WHERE Email = @Email)
BEGIN
UPDATE tblRegister
  SET Passwordd=@Passwordd where Email=@Email
END
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Store Procedure ( Please use  **IF EXISTS**)

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE InsertName
    (
      @Email varchar(25), 
      @Passwordd varchar(25)
    )
    AS
    IF EXISTS(SELECT 'True' FROM tblRegister WHERE Email = @Email)
    BEGIN
      --This means it exists,update
      UPDATE tblRegister
          SET Passwordd=@Passwordd where Email=@Email
 SELECT 'Changed successfully'
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
      --This means the record isn't in there already
      SELECT 'Does Not Exist' 
    END

private string ChangePassword()
{
    string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABCD"].ConnectionString;
    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
    {
        con.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spChangePassword", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email",txtEmail.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passwordd", txtPassword.Text);
        return cmd.ExecuteNonQuery().ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: I did't comment other answers, All other answer is good. but why(OP) you did't accept that? hmm !  i will accept all answers. they give good answers

Answer (score 0):

SQL

```
Create proc spChangePassword
  @Email varchar(100),
  @Passwordd varchar(100)
as
begin
 IF EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM tblRegister WHERE Email = @Email)
  BEGIN
   UPDATE tblRegister
    SET Passwordd=@Passwordd where Email=@Email
  END
 ELSE
  BEGIN
   RAISEERROR('Email does not exists',0,1)
  END
end
```

c#

```
string CS = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ABCD"].ConnectionString;
using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(CS))
{
    try{
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spChangePassword", con);
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email",txtEmail.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Passwordd", txtPassword.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch(SqlException ee)
    {
      ...
    }
}
```